# Should accepted answers appear first, just above the highest scored answer, or should answers now appear only in order of score? (Vote by Oct. 19)

Tags: discussion

| Moderator note |  |
| --- | --- |
| After a period for voting including as a featured question, votes have been tallied on this question as of 16:50UTC on 19 October, and the results are as follows. Note that *only upvotes have been counted* as this is a binary choice. There is a clear winner. The third option is interesting but was not part of the original SE proposal. |  |
| Answers should appear only in order of score (this is the new behavior on Stack Overflow) | 14 |
| **The accepted answer should appear on top (this is the status quo)** | **21** |
| Pinning the accepted answer below the top voted answer | 9 |
| The accepted answer should appear on top | 5 |
| Answer making an argument for unpinning | 5 |
| Pin the accepted answer | 2 |
| The MSE question has been updated with this result. Andrew Leach ♦ |  |

For the full background, please see [this MSE question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/369568/273503).

In short, currently, if the question-asker “accepts” one of the answers, that answer is “pinned” to the top position, shown to all visitors at the top of the page, the rest of the posts appearing in order of score, so that the highest voted post, if different, appears directly beneath it.

It was noticed on StackOverflow [this caused problems for that site](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/411352/2562182). The most pressing problem for  SO, which is technically oriented, is that old, obsolete, or dangerously outdated answers could and would be shown before more updated or correct ones. SO posts often get thousands of views by voting users long after the original question is posted, and so new answers often rapidly accrue votes and over-take highly upvoted, previous, out-of-date answers. Therefore now SO shows answers (if using the default sort) strictly in descending score order.

This turned out to be popular for that particular site, and so now the Powers That Be are asking their other sites for their preferences.

So, do we want to take the option? Would you prefer the status quo, where the OP-accepted answer is shown first (except where the OP themself posted the answer, of course), or should we switch to strictly score-based sorting

To inform your decision, you can view the [complete list of which answers would be affected on Main](https://data.stackexchange.com/english/query/1466399/questions-with-accepted-answer-pinned-above-highest-scoring-answer-on-elu) (6,888 answers; average score difference between accepted and top-voted = 4.6 pts) and [Meta](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.english/query/1466399/questions-with-accepted-answer-pinned-above-highest-scoring-answer-on-elu) (137 answers; average score difference between accepted and top-voted = 4.25 pts). Note that the settings for Main and Meta are independent; we can unpin on Main and keep the pin on Meta, for example.

---

<sub>It would be best if answers to this question took a concrete, binary stance — keep pinned or unpin — and optionally, but encouraged, a rationale.</sub>

Mod note (Andrew Leach ♦): Because there is a binary stance, only vote up the answer you support. **Only the upvotes on each stance will be counted.** If you vote up one answer and vote down the other, you effectively double your vote, which is undesirable.

Comment: This [discussion about a highly upvoted but wrong answer](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/q/12089/80039) may offer some food for thought. I'm not saying it supports pinning or unpinning, but it was a real controversial question on ELU where pinning the accepted answer had an effect.

Comment: @ColleenV Thanks! I think that situation argues for the unpinning of the accepted answer, because presumably the flagger who got it deleted already downvoted, but was hopeless because the answer was still stuck at the top, over the “very good, nuanced answer”.

Comment: Currently the  better answer is pinned though, so it cuts both ways. Looking at the timeline, I don't think the incorrect answer was ever accepted, it was just highly voted.

Comment: @ColleenV Sure. A level playing field where the prize is awarded to the answer that attracted most community agreement is what I favor. If the “bad” answer got more votes, well … *it got more votes*.

Comment: @ColleenV BTW, feel free to post an answer taking the “keep the status quo” position if you’re still inclined. We need both positions for the Metazens to vote on.

Comment: To be transparent, I'm in favor of unpinning. I think it was a poorly thought out way to accomplish an ill-defined goal. I think if we understood the goal better we would have done something other than pinning.

Comment: @ColleenV As you can see, I am too. I had wanted it for years, and nothing to do with SO’s (ill defined, as you say) problem with obsolescent technology. I’ve only ever seen the accepted answer be meaningfully outscored by competing answers when the OP churlishly accepted it because everyone else disagreed with him.

Comment: I think it might be OK to give the asker a way to highlight an answer. Maybe interested readers could use a link to jump directly the author's favorite answer. I don't think it should be mixed in with the ranking  of the quality of the answers.

Comment: @ColleenV Yeah, that’s all fine by me. I think the green check mark will still who you, visually, and likely the Q entry in the list of questions will still have a different background color, so we’ve got highlighting sorted already.

Comment: Also related: [Is it correct that a user chooses the correct answer?](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7947/).

Comment: @ColleenV (revised) the very popular but incorrect answer "If I was vs If I were” was indeed accepted by the OP but it was [**unaccepted** on 7 February, 2018](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/30/edward-tanguay?tab=reputation&sort=post&page=8) The OP changed their mind eight years later.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Thanks - that is why I think that particular discussion and question are useful when thinking about pinning. It could be argued that the pinning contributed to a bad answer being promoted for a while, but now pinning is helping the better answer make up ground in terms of votes.

Comment: @DanBron Not sure that the last edit is necessarily A Good Thing, as the first few lines shown at https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions are not actually what should appear in that context.

Comment: @AndrewLeach Ah, ok. Good point.  I’ll roll it back.

Comment: @DanBron Some users amuse themselves by hanging around giving early answers to SWRs. They know full-well that the early answer catches the worm. The problem is the early answer is not necessarily the best. Quite often the opposite. But early answers garner upvotes and upvoted answers also garner upvotes.  I'm prepared to live with the gamers who enjoy the popular show that is SWRs on EL&U, but not when those contributors promote the destruction of the checks and balances built into the system to promote good, not early, answers.

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore. I know the SWR-hugger type you mean. It’s part of why I consider rep meaningless (though not the biggest part). I’ve read all the comments you’ve left in this thread, and I’ve ended up at: I agree with jw that you point out real deficiencies in the voting system, no question. But I also agree with jw that the fix isn’t pinning accepted answers; it puts too much power in one person’s hand. In fact, that’s my main complaint with it: more often than serving as a positive check against mob voting, I see accept-pin *abused* by petulant OPs who don’t want to see the truth.

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore. And just so it’s out there: I have not voted on anything in this thread. I am the author of the Q and two (competing) answers, so the system prevents me from voting on them, and I disagree with the two remaining answers (my rationale for disagreement with yours is the immediately preceding comment), which means if I voted, I’d vote down, but the rules of the game Andrew set out mean I’m precluded from doing that as well. So I’m not influencing the final results at all; I’ll happily accept whatever consensus emerges. I figure 7 days total will let the dust settle.

Comment: @AndrewLeach Ok, it’s been a week, and the votes have been stable for a few days. We have about 11 for unpin (the 10 upvotes on my unpin answer, plus myself who can’t vote on it), and 6 for keep pinned (the 6 upvotes on the keep pinned answer I posted). I’m not sure how to account for the votes on the other answers, but I suspect some keep-pinned users voted on both (and anyway even if we count them independently the total is still < 11). Thus I intend to edit the MSE post to say EL&U wants to unpin. If you disagree or think it premature, feel free to roll back my edit.

Comment: @DanBron Araucaria's answer has only been present for two or three days and may be subject to its own Reason Number 4. I'd suggest holding off for a bit.

Comment: @AndrewLeach Fair enough, but I’m not clear on how we will distinguish votes on his answer from votes on the earlier keep-pinned answer in terms of deciding whether to keep pinned or unpin. I’m happy to hold off fir any amount of time. I’ll check back in in a week.

Comment: @DanBron Just report all the answers+votes, or simply direct staff to this question and let them make up their own mind!

Comment: @AndrewLeach They’ve already been directed to this post in a table summarizing all child meta Qs on this topic. That brake also reports the conclusions in a single column which indicates either “keep pin” or “unpin”. I edited a link to this meta-Q into that table when I posted it. Now all the remains is editing in our conclusion. That’s what I was describing above.

Comment: -1 for **not editing your post** (why do I have to search through the comments?) and [not announcing the decision to unpin](https://meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/369914/57) and for not saying you have edited the aforementioned MSE post.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I said in an earlier comment I’d give it another week and I gave it another week. Another user rolled back my edit dude to the post scores being now equal (disregarding the upvotes-only rule), so I will wait yet another week, and I will edit the MSE post again according to the upvotes on each position. We need to make a decision.m: keep pinned or unpin. If keep pinned has more upvoted in a week I’ll edit the MSE post to say keep the pin, and vice versa.

Comment: @jsw29 I think “hot meta questions” is controlled by activity on the thread. Though maybe diamond-mods can nominate it to show up? Not sure. And good point on the title — I am very open to collaboration here on SE, so if you have ideas about how to make it clearer or more compelling to engage with, please feel free to edit the Q to your heart’s content.

Comment: @jsw29 where did this community agree on the 12 October deadline? Also, Dan and jsw29, I hope you are not considering to make a decision (at least in terms of announcing it on the Meta.SE post) based only on upvotes (or net votes) as you can see links [in this comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/369568/unpinning-the-accepted-answer-from-the-top-of-the-list-of-answers/369914?noredirect=1#comment1237037_369914) to 3 different pages explaining why determining consensus is more complicated than just tallying votes in a poll. Do you have arguments against the 16 points by Araucaria?

Comment: @jsw29 Thanks for explaining that to me. Please remove the deadline from the title since it was decided unilaterally in a comment by Mr. Bron, or bilaterally by you and Mr. Bron, which constitutes only 2 people who both happen to be on the same side of this debate about pinning vs unpinning. If reaching a consensus seems unlikely, that's okay, but if we don't reach one we have to stick to the status quo and put 50/50 in the Meta.SE post like Academia.SE and other sites did.

Comment: @NikeDattani We need some deadline.  It doesn't have to be the 12th but it has to be something.  Not making a decision is, as I explained to others, making a decision.  I've happily pushed it back a couple times, and I'll happily do it again if activity on the thread warrants it.  As for determining what that decision is: all the other sites which have updated the MSE post have done it on the strength of votes, so far as I can tell.  That's the point of making arguments & assessing their persuasiveness to the community. Having said that, \new method is for a mod to add "status review" for a CM

Comment: Furthermore, it's not 50/50; that would be misrepresenting the situation.  More people want to unpin than pin. That's the reality at this point in time.  No one is obliged to make a point-by-point rebuttal to Arucaria's 14 points; one makes the arguments they want to make and people vote on them.  I imagine the CM who reviews the "status review" will do exactly what the other sites have done: look at the votes and decide that way.  They will likely view making their *own* assessments of the arguments and deciding that way to be audacious in overriding the will of the community.

Comment: @DanBron You (and jsw29 alone) don't get to unilaterally decide the deadline though. In fact, who other than you said that "we need some deadline"? On Physics.SE the decision was made prematurely, and after the accepted answers became unpinned there was a surge in votes for re-pinning them (the scores changed from 19/12 to 20/18, and now a mod there has decided that if it swing the other way around, the pinning behavior will also have to switch. That's also what a CM has suggested. So there's no deadline. No mod should add "status review" unless community consensus has been clearly established

Comment: @NikeDattani Because *not making a decision is making a decision*. The deadline has been extended a couple times *because of new activity in the thread*. So long as the votes are changing, it’s worth re-extending. But we can’t extend indefinitely *because not making a decision is making a decision*. As for why me, or jsw, or anyone else: because this is how meta sites are run: it’s on us, the regulars of the community to drive meta and make community decisions. It’s not on the mods, it’s not on the CMs, it’s on us. It’s our duty, and it’s our call.

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore. since it's "our call", shall we remove the "deadline" that was created unilaterally by just two people in favor of unpinning? Shall we accept a consensus based on only votes (whether upvotes or net votes) which could easily be manipulated by voting fraud, meatpupetting, or canvassing, or should we take a more sophisticated approach as explained in the [three links in this comment](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15144/should-accepted-answers-continue-to-appear-first-even-when-they-are-not-the-mos?noredirect=1#comment61229_15144)?

Comment: @NikeDattani I’m not going to rehash the same topics. This will be my last comment. We need a deadline, so we have a deadline, though we can and will be flexible about it. We will use votes because there is no other way to determine what *the consensus actually is*; you might find A’s 14 pts compelling, I might not, and vice versa. How do we know? Voting. If voting fraud is rampant, we have bigger problems to worry about than pinning the accepted answer. If you need comfort there will be a sanity check, the CM status-review should provide that. Thanks, nice talking to you.

Comment: We didn't agree that we need a deadline. I already explained in my comment (4 comments before this one, including your comments) that having a "deadline" was problematic on Physics.SE for the pinning/unpinning debate and that a CM implied that there will be no "deadline" .. if one view overtakes another, then a decision on the pinning can be reversed. Araucaria enumerated 16 points, yet you make it look like it was less, by saying it was only 14. Consensus is not always determined by voting, it's determined by a more sophisticated process. Sometimes the right decision is "no consensus".

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore. Thanks for making that post! I think you should undelete your post from here though. Perhaps you're worried that the meager net score of 4 was making it look like your answer was not supported, but I think people could see that it was a much newer answer, and that other people were writing comments saying to only vote on the first two answers. I think that answer you wrote, was actually very helpful for this discussion. Especially if someone does decide to convince a mod to add the "status-review" tag, we would want the CMs to see your answer before making a decision

Comment: @NikeDattani My feeling is that overly long, detailed posts are not as effective, and overkill is off-putting to readers! I'm also wary of being seen to try to double up. One good more concise post is better than a good one and a rambling one!

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore. perhaps you can at least put the 16 enumerated points back up. Those are at least quite *concise*.

Comment: @NikeDattani I'll wait and see what's happening over the next 3 or 4 days. If there's no movement, I'll put the enumerated points back up.

Comment: If the voting is close, why choose? We can already sort by date or votes, so why not have a check-box so users can decide for ourselves whether to pin accepted answers?

Comment: @Lawrence, 'Why choose?', because, as Dan Brown, points out, 'not making a decision is making a decision' in favour of the accepted answer appearing on top. Giving people an option to arrange the answers as you propose would also require that a decision to that effect be made. Providing that option may work well for the regular users, but some of us are mostly concerned in this debate with the impact of the order of answers on the casual, infrequent visitors (who are likely to see only the default order, even if other options are available).

Comment: @jsw29 If that's the case, why do you support the position that you do? The evidence shows that, where there's a discrepancy, accepted answers are more likely to be later answers than earlier answers compared to the most highly upvoted one. In other words, askers are judicious in their selection of accepted answers. Unlike early voters.

Comment: @jsw29 In addition users can currently easily see both accepted and most highly upvoted answers as they appear together at the top together. Your preferred system means that late, useful, accepted answers will often disappear under a load of mediocre answers. Are you scared of accepted answers showing up highly voted ones? Your proposal is not great for EL&U, because EL&U does not work like SO. C'mon! Look after real users here. Keep the useful, appreciated-by-users  accepted answer feature. (If you unpin it, you can kiss it goodbye. No one will scroll down and new users won't know it exists!

Comment: @jsw29 Well, it's worth noting that in the vast majority of cases the highest voted answer **is** the accepted answer (but that proportion might go down if the new proposal gets implemented. Accepting an answer gives it visibility which can increase its upvotes). That's a good thing. But in those cases where it doesn't, both the highest scoring answer and the accepted one appear, helpfully, at the top of the page! In the proposed scenario, the accepted one, which is statistically more likely to be newer may remain buried at the bottom. The first may be imperfect, but the latter is a real loss.

Comment: @AndrewLeach It’s now the 19th and the votes are very stable. Will you ping a CM for [meta-tag:status-review] on this question? That’s the process the updated MSE thread asks us to go through. Since the votes are unambiguously for the status quo, I think the CM won’t have to do much. I’ll go edit the “keep pin” into the MSE answer now.

Comment: @AndrewLeach Thanks for this. I think "The accepted answer should appear on top" Q has been given the balance (5) as opposed to the upvotes (8)! [I don't want to edit, because I'm not sure I'm right]

Comment: Since your consensus ended up being to keep the status-quo, there was no need to escalate this for CM attention. I'll remove the [tag:status-review] tag, and leave things as they are.

Comment: @JNat  Why am I not seeing the accepted answer pinned at the top? https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/333934/this-for-a-game-of-soldiers?answertab=votes#tab-top

Comment: But here the accepted answer is always pinned https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/42449/what-is-the-origin-of-the-idiom-let-something-rip?answertab=active#tab-top

Comment: Your first link is a self-accept, and those were never pinned to the top, @Mari-LouA

Comment: Oh, I didn't notice. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 18):

#### The accepted answer should appear on top (this is the status quo).

---

We have the opposite problem to Stack Overflow. Answers on SO often get thousands of views and votes by active voting members long after a question is posted. New posts can therefore easily overtake an early accepted answer. Here, however, the number of views by active voting members bombs after about 48 hours. The only way of promoting a later, superior, more helpful answer and making it easily visible to readers is through the 'accepted answer' mechanism.

We are on the verge of having many of the best answer posts on EL&U suddenly consigned to obscurity under a pile of mediocre early answers, reducing the value of this site to readers.

An accepted answer says that it was **the *most helpful* to the author of the question** regardless of the number of votes it may have accrued. It tells the community that to all intents and purposes the problem has been solved.

Despite the differences in scores, the author of the accepted answer may have understood the OP's dilemma better than a higher scored answer. And sometimes the OP may change their mind and accept a better, more nuanced answer that was posted days, weeks or even years later.  If I am the author of the question I would like to *thank* the user by accepting their answer and seeing it pinned at the top of the page. This shows my gratitude and it has the given advantage of being read first, and it will lead to more upvotes if it is seen at the top of the page rather than lost in a sea of answers.

Finally, the top answer is not necessarily the "best". HNQ visitors are not always the most objective or knowledgeable in the field of language. Native speakers have an instinct that is matchless to any artificial intelligence software or language learner but that doesn't mean they are able to explain or understand why one answer is superior to another.

For instance, this question  ["Closet" vs. "Wardrobe" Why is the first more common in the US?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/422265/closet-vs-wardrobe-why-is-the-first-more-common-in-the-us) posted on December 14 2017 at 12:49 has three visible answers. The “best” answer, with **87 upvotes**, was posted on the same day at 13:39. But the author of the question accepted [an answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/423148/44619) which was posted six days later. Was the author of the question wrong to accept an answer with only **13 upvotes**? Does that answer not deserve the top position?  You be the judge.

—

Another reason for pinning the accepted answer at the top is that **it keeps the two most significant answers at the top**, namely, the accepted answer and the most popular of the other answers. And it does so without additional programming, compared to sorting by votes and then pinning the accepted answer below the top-voted answer (if they are different answers).

Comment: Arranging answers strictly by vote count would make more sense if all answers appeared at approximately the same time and were seen by approximately the same number of prospective up- and downvoters. But in reality, answers may appear years after a question is posed—and if a late-arriving answer is good enough to win the question poster's check mark after such a delay, it seems a shame to leave it at or near the bottom of the stack just because it wasn't around when the earlier answers started attracting upvotes.

Comment: @SvenYargs This is a CW answer. Feel free to edit in that argument if you’re so inclined. (Also if you want to talk to the author of it, you need to explicitly @-ping ML, otherwise I’ll be the only one notified. CWs get messy that way.)

Comment: This may be a good argument for the existence of the institution of accepting, in addition to voting, but it doesn't really support displaying the accepted answers above those with the highest net votes. It may well be that 'the author of the accepted answer . . . understood the OP's dilemma better than a higher scored answer' and that the answer was 'the most helpful **to** the author of the question', but that doesn't mean the answer is likely to be more helpful **to** the future visitors to the page, and it is their interests that should govern how the answers are displayed.

Comment: @SvenYargsSven please  edit the post in any way you please. I don't mind if some lines are  deleted  or even its entire content.  Start from scratch if that makes it easier. I already knew this would be an uphill battle.

Comment: @jsw29 `and it is their (future visitors) interests that should govern how the answers are displayed` I disagree, the author of the question has a higher status than a visitor or a user who casts their vote. Without questions there would be no answers. Without questions there would be no Q&A SE sites. By diminishing the value of the questioner, we *could* see fewer answers being accepted in the future because it will become unclear what its purpose was.

Comment: Why should an accepted answer come at or near the bottom of a pile because of the number of upvotes it's received? We have all seen answers that attracted ridiculous number of upvotes thanks to HNQ.  A huge crowd of visitors is great way for posters to earn rep but it is not analogous to people who are experts or passionate about the subject.  Sometimes I agree with the most upvoted answer but not always, and if I am the author of the Q my opinion should count. And if the person asking is an expert in the field, then even more so their opinion should be valued.

Comment: This fear that visitors will learn something incorrect or be mislead by an accepted answer with lower votes is a false one. Why? Because whenever an accepted answer is objectively bad or incorrect it attracts mass downvoting, as well it should. Remove the accepted answer from its top position that same bad answer might be shrugged off or completely ignored. Even LQ accepted answers serve a purpose. See [tchrist's fascinating answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/429514/44619) posted in 2018 to a 2010 question. Were it not for the old accepted answer, that answer would not exist.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I'm voting here based on the general expectation. Yes, there are lots of exceptions (late good answers, voters voting for non-substantive reasons, multiple good answers, what -I- want from -my- question vs what others want). There's also an issue of tyranny  of the majority, high voted questions tending to get more votes not (or not necessarily) because they are good but because they are highly voted already.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Sorry for being so telegraphic...only so many letters can fit in a box. I am choosing my vote based on those criteria and those criteria led me to vote up on unpinning. Also, I think I may have waffled on which box to put this in, thus misleading you. I just wanted to give an explanation in addition to voting.

Comment: Wow! Six upvotes in less than two days. What happened?!

Answer (score 9):

#### Answers should appear only in order of score (this is the new behavior on Stack Overflow).

The mandate of SE in general is to create a “[library of reusable knowledge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/343338/273503)”, and each site attempts to do that in its subject area by attracting and retaining domain experts.

Those experts become “the community”, and the community expresses its will — and that very domain expertise — principally through voting.

I do not think it advances our agenda to allow one question asker — who, by definition, does not know the correct answer to his question — to outweigh the aggregate opinion of this expert community.

The “accept” button should and does express “this is the answer which most helped *the OP*”, and it still will, even after this change. The difference will be the first-listed answer will be more likely to *help anyone else who has the same question* down the road.

On a more practical level, I really only see situations where the accepted answer having a lower score than some or most other answers when the OP came in with an axe to grind and accepted the answer which [best flattered his preconceptions, despite everyone else disputing it](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/70852/55623). There are even cases where a [diamond moderator had to delete the accepted answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/posts/190515/revisions) (10K+ only link) because it was highly controversial and didn’t meet the standards for an “answer” on EL&U.

Comment: But [this answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/662/21450) in comparison to the accepted one, supports **keeping things the way they are**.

Comment: While I agree that an answer that has >30 upvotes  is likely to be very good, when the difference between the answer accepted and the most *popular* is <10, who is to say that the OP does not recognize a *right* answer when it is posted? It is up the answerer to convince not only the community but also the OP. And sometimes the author of the question *does* know the answer and they post the question for the greater benefit of the community and its "library". In those cases they *do* know which is the best answer.

Comment: Lastly, HNQ visitors are not always the most objective or knowledgeable in the field of language. Native speakers have an instinct that is unmatchable to any artificial intelligence or language learner but that doesn't mean they are able to *explain* or understand why one answer is superior to another.

Comment: @Mari-LouA HNQ is a good point, but those questions are anomalies on many dimensions anyway. I’m not stressed about them. I’ll add links to this Meta-Q later today so you can see exactly which answers on Main would be effected if we adopted this change.

Comment: I see only one option to vote for! It would be nice a **Keep it pinned** box for anyone brave enough to cast their vote against the current flow. :)

Comment: @Mari-LouA (a) There's nothing stopping you creating that post. (b) Only upvotes should be counted in a two-post contest, in order that people cannot vote up one post and vote down the other and effectively double their vote.

Comment: @Mari-LouA [I totally agree](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15144/would-elu-like-the-accepted-answer-to-be-unpinned#comment61118_15144) we need the other answer posted so people can vote on it. The issue with me personally posting it is I am not in that camp; my arguments would be weak if I’m honest and disingenuous if I try my best to make them strong. But I am hopeful someone who does strongly support pinning will post an answer taking that position with the strongest arguments they can muster. I want Meta to work the way it’s supposed to work.

Comment: @Mari-LouA [As you like](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/a/15146/55623). Please see the footnote.

Comment: Abusing the Q&A format to gather feedback has some real drawbacks, like not being able to upvote the community wiki you create to let people vote on a proposal. It is probably for the best to let someone who would not upvote the proposal make the wiki answer and let the folks that want to upvote it flesh out the content. If I had thought about this earlier, I would have just created the "pinned" answer.

Comment: @ColleenV Yep, that’s what we did here. ML couldn’t post it because she wanted to upvote it. So I posted it as a blank CE and she filled out the arguments for the position, and then upvoted it.

Comment: I saw that and it lit the lightbulb, that's all I meant to say :) Now, who is going to upvote the other answer you wrote for you?

Comment: @ColleenV ML upvoted the answer; that's why we proceeded her way. But don't think of it as *my* answer; the one we are currently commenting on is my answer. The other is more properly speaking ML's answer. Obviously, I can't vote on it. Given my position is anti-pin, if I were to, I'd vote it down, but as Edwin noted, even if I could do that, it would effectively be double-voting (+1 for unpin and -1 for keep pin), so I would recuse myself in any case.

Comment: @DanBron No, I mean, who will upvote the answer you support for you, because you can't due to authoring it... It should get an implicit +1 :)

Comment: @ColleenV Ah, I see.  Well, it's one vote.  We'll see how it comes out in the balance.

Comment: A check mark is a visible "thank you" and may influence future readers in search of an answer, but poser is equal to all other voters and gets only one up/downvote in "community judgement". I vote to keep answer order fully dynamic.  // Just as there is a green square on the main page to indicate that question has an accepted answer, I suggest that if the decision is to unpin, we request a similar small symbol on the answer page to reminder readers that there *is* an accepted answer below (if it doesn't happen to be at the top.)

Comment: @Mari-LouA My reasoning for not wanting the accepted answer pinned to to the top has two assumptions. 1) the question poser -doesn't know the answer-, that's why they're asking, and further they are likely not to have the knowledge to judge the correctness. An accept by the OP doesn't mean an answer is right, but that it was most helpful to the OP. 2) Though the question is motivated by a single user, the answers are read and judged by everybody, so the utility of the accepted answer to all the other users  is questionable, that is I see votes as a better marker of quality than the OP's check.

Comment: A third solution, hinted at by something we all see everyday but are blind to, is about the choices we are already given on sorting. Right before the answers there are three buttons to choose the sort order. We can choose to sort by post time, activity time, or votes. Though this is a very subtle, thing, SE could also put a button to say 'pin accepted' (the UX reason being that it is another possible preference by users).

Comment: @Mitch Voting order is most often an indication of when the answer was posted. Voters don't get notified when new answers, which may be definitive, provide real evidence etc appear. There is only the remotest semblance of peer review here because far more users have upvote privileges than downvote ones, and also only the remotest semblance of democracy because early posted answers have thousands more opportunities to be upvoted than later ones, especially those  posted months or years after the original question. It's misleading to pretend early answers aren't artificially promoted.

Comment: @Mitch And thus misleading to pretend that highly upvoted answers would be more highly regarded by the community. The community just didn't see the later ones. The accepted answer feature is one check in the face of this problem.

Comment: @Araucaria : you make a number of excellent points about voting (excellent because I have thought them too but didn't put into words yet),  but almost entirely your arguments are about sorting by voting 
and pinning by 'accept' is either irrelevant or remotely related to fixing the voting problem. Most of your complaints could be fixed for you by sorting by activity.

Comment: @Mitch But the OP is the only user notified of new answers, which may be well-argued or supported. No one else is in this position. (See my overly long answer below). And there is no other remedy to overcome this problem. They are the keeper at the gate ...

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore. Yes, the OP is the only one who sees all the activity. I think then that it is a matter of opinion whether you think the OP is a good assessor of what the best answer is -and- if you think that is more important that voting. You have pointed out a very important problem with any voting on things that are presented (like answers) at different times or where everybody sees the voting counts before voting. But I am not convinced that a user 'accepted' mark, or in addition such a mark leading to it being put at the top comes anywhere near helping.

Comment: **10 votes in favour of leaving the accepted answer** at the top. **12 votes for changing** the sorting order with pinning the most upvoted answer at the top. **13** if we include your vote, I guess. But I hardly call this a universal consensus. And you are not a moderator who gets to make that final decision but I suspect you had their full support.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Didn’t get an inbox notification for this, somehow. Anyway, yes, that’s the math. And I agree it’s not universal consensus but we’re here to make a decision, and these are the best tools we’ve got. Not making a decision leaves the status quo, which itself *is* making a decision. There’s no way around it. I will note that the majority of child meta votes on this issue have decided on unpinning, leaving aside that’s now fait accompli on the biggest site, SO, itself. I didn’t interact with the mods and they didn’t do anything on this Q outside the public comments and edits you see.

Comment: @Mari-LouA And going by upvotes, currently, the score is actually +15 (+16 if you count my implied vote on this answer) vs +10. Given we only had ~30 people vote, that’s a majority, at least.

Comment: There's a wider margin now, I hope these latecomers and last minute upvotes are from regular users of EL&U but there's no way of knowing. I hereby wave my white flag, not sure what Araucaria makes of the results but the results are unlikely to be overturned... unless we're still waiting to hear from Pennsylvania, Arizona and Georgia :))

Comment: @Mari-LouA Hahaha! Though it kinda makes me sad that my country is now the international poster child for messy elections. But cheer up, there’s hope for Camp Keep Pinned yet. I revisited the MSE post today and they’ve changed the method for setting the configuration on a site; a week ago, editing the answer there was sufficient. Now we have to ask a mod to add [meta-tag:status-review] to *this* question to have a CM come and make their own determination of consensus. As I promised, I’ll wait another week before pinging Andrew to do that for us.

Comment: @Mari-LouA what do you mean by "the results are unlikely to be overturned"?  You mean the vote counts are unlikely to switch? On Physics.SE they prematurely decided to unpin when the score was 19 for "unpin" and 12 for "keep pin" and then when SE implemented it, there was a surge of support for "keep pin", so the score is now 20 for "unpin" and 18 for "keep pin". See the three links in [this comment](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15144/should-accepted-answers-continue-to-appear-first-even-when-they-are-not-the-mos?noredirect=1#comment61229_15144): *Votes don't tell all.*

Comment: @NikeDattani Same happened on [Academia](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5010/should-the-answer-that-appears-on-top-be-the-ops-accepted-answer-or-the-ans) in terms of the vote *completely* reversing in the end.

Comment: @NikeDattani  (1) All I can say is that after I posted my comment pointing out the narrow margin, the next day three more votes were posted supporting the change. The  post is on meta, it was featured on the bulletin for weeks, the lack of response and debate  also counts. Low rep users are probably oblivious of the feature and the majority of veterans are absent and largely indifferent.

Comment: (2) I see that the current system works. Never ever did anyone post on EL&U complaining specifically about the accepted answer. When it was mentioned it was in connection to a bad or demonstrably incorrect answer, which shows that the system works. A bad answers was highlighted when it was accepted by the OP, but good answers were upvoted even more so. The vast majority of users **posting questions** are not idiots, they have usually invested energy and time in their question and are happy when two or more answers are posted.

Comment: I'm taken aback by the swing of votes. As of today the results have been completely overturned. **19** for keeping the **accepted answer at the top** and only  **15** (including yours) in favour of  placing the **highest scored answer** st the top.

Comment: @Mari-LouA it’s surprising to me too, I saw that a couple of them were un-upvotes for unpinning; presumably these then went to keep-pinning. That suggests to me an appeal was made in chat, maybe. Regardless, the tally’s the tally. If the community wants the pin, we’ll keep the pin.

Answer (score 8):

There is an interesting idea on Meta [suggesting pinning the accepted answer **below** the top voted answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/370156/273494). That system might give an advantage to the accepted answer over other highly scored answers, but never over the top voted answer.

I'd like to know if anyone thinks that would be worth testing. We may not be able to choose that option for this effort, but if there's interest we might be able to get it on SE's radar.

Comment: I’m in the camp that acceptance really doesn’t need any special attention. I’d buy your feature to put a little direct link to the accepted answer in the footer of the Q, or sort the accepted answer higher than other answers with exactly equal score, but that’s about the extent of it. I think the acceptance mechanism was introduced to solve the main problem with forums in 2008: quickly getting to *the answer* in a sea of irrelevant comments, but I think by now we’ve learned that forcing all answers *to be answers* is more than adequate for that need. OP’s opinion shouldn’t carry more weight.

Comment: @DanBron I tend to agree, but I thought the idea was interesting enough to try to get it in front of more people.

Comment: @DanBron I'm in the camp where SWR's and similar should not be taken too seriously when considering how the site should be run. for non SWR-type questions, acceptance is a good indicator of several things, though not perfect. But it's there to counteract another non-perfect system, the so-called 'voting' one. That's why it's desperately needed.

Comment: To see why I downvoted this proposal, please see the end of my post :)

Comment: I like the idea (+1), but I’d put the accepted answer on top. If it isn’t the top-voted answer, then that answer will only be one position away from the top. You get both answers (top + accepted) at / near the top without any additional programming.

Answer (score 5):

#### The accepted answer should appear on top!

I urge readers to vote to pin the accepted answer at the top of the page. This feature does a lot of silent good work whilst the very few annoying instances where an OP picks a (seemingly) obviously wrong answer are very scarce indeed, however memorable these are (see [Cag51's post on Academia and the information therein](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5010/should-the-answer-that-appears-on-top-be-the-ops-accepted-answer-or-the-ans/5015#5015)).

Despite the terms *voting* and *upvoted*, there is a severe problem in terms of how democratic the voting system is. Early posts get voted on a lot, later posts much, much  less so. Around 48+ hours after a question is first posted, the number of views by active voting members drops off significantly.

Pinning the accepted answer allows relatively 'late'-arriving but excellent and helpful answers to be recognised and pinned to the top of the page where they currently benefit readers. Without this feature some of the best and most helpful information on the site will languish unseen  underneath a list of earlier mediocre answer posts. This current system still retains the benefit of having the highest-voted answer directly beneath the selected one. The new one will see many existing good posts vanish into obscurity.

Another benefit of the current system is that the Original Poster is the only member who is routinely alerted to new answers, especially those that arrive weeks, months or years after the question is originally posted. Because of this, they are in by far the best position to curate their own question page, and, if appropriate, accept a late answer. Certainly, the slew of voters on the original few answers  will not be notified and will not get the chance to vote anew on the full range of answers.

Lastly, the current system affords some respect and agency to people who ask questions on the site. Whilst there are always vaguely annoying members in every aspect of the daily life of every SE site, we don't allow this to destroy or make us abandon useful and helpful features of the site. Where the odd muddle-headed OP might select the wrong answer, this is rarely anything more than an annoyance, and a rare one. In contrast if we in essence lose the selected answer feature, users will lose the benefit of many excellent posts and the helpful information that they provide. The vast majority of people asking questions here are sensible adults fully capable of making appropriate decisions regarding selected answers.

Some SE sites, for instance SO, get thousands and thousands of views by active voting members. So, for example, the highest voted answer on SO has over 33,000 votes. On these sites a very high number of votes over a quite sustained period may be the best indicator of the accuracy and helpfulness of an answer. Here, however, this is not the case.

The voting system on *English Language & Usage* is a good thing. However, it is not perfect for many reasons, including those detailed above. The 'accepted answer' feature helps provide checks and balances within the system. In particular it defends against the unintended and unwelcome tyranny of the early upvoted answer. Just like a healthy democracy, where second chambers and the separation of the legislature, the judiciary and the police provide safety in the form of checks and balances, the same is true of the accepted answer feature in its current form. Vote to keep it!

Comment: Regarding point 2, I found [3383 questions where later answers outscore the accepted answer](https://data.stackexchange.com/english/query/1467559/) and [4353 questions where a lower scoring accepted answer was posted after the highest scoring answer](https://data.stackexchange.com/english/query/1467560/). Browsing the results, I'd say it's also common that lower quality answers are pinned. It'd be interesting to know how often the most researched answers get snowed under now vs. under the proposal, but I think it requires a qualitative analysis. Perhaps it's doable by taking a small sample?

Comment: Point 10. Truth be told when a new answer is posted, it bumps the question up on the home page. Edited posts and new answers are rushed to the front of the queue. Nevertheless the newer better  answer will always attract fewer views. An exception can be made for old questions that are visited tens of thousands of times. A new better answer will slowly  earn upvotes every time that question visited and when it is bumped to the front.

Comment: BUT if the newer better answer is ***accepted*** AND ***pinned*** at the top of the page it stands a better chance of getting read by future visitors especially if there are dozens of other answers.

Comment: All regular contributors to this site would probably agree that the voting system is far from perfect and that the answers with the highest score are often not really the best ones. The question here, however, is not whether that net votes are the perfect indicator of which answers are the best, but whether they are better indicators than acceptances. Yes, it is possible that a very thoughtful questioner's acceptance will counter the unfairness of the votes, but does that happen more often than the acceptance being awarded to an answer that is worse than the one with the highest score?

Comment: @jsw29 Yes, I believe it does. And most often on questions where it actually matters. At any rate, under the current system the top-voted answer is pinned directly under the accepted one, so there's no great loss there. However, there will be when the accepted answer disappears out of view. I'd say it's routine for answerers such as Prof Lawler to come late to questions, get accepted and then garner the upvotes from that. I used to answer a lot of old questions knowing that I wasn't going to get much rep, but wanting to get the accepted answer so that future readers would be helped by my post.

Comment: @jsw29 This post on [Academia SE](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5010/should-the-answer-that-appears-on-top-be-the-ops-accepted-answer-or-the-ans/5015#5015) shows that, even on rather unfortunately uninformative scales used, only a very, very small number of posts seemed to have egregiously disfavoured answers accepted. However, there were a very significant proportion of posts where the accepted answer appeared much later than the highest voted one. This suggests that far from being fickle, obstinate and dimwitted OP's are being extremely careful, considered and judicious.

Comment: +1 from me. The decision in favour of changing, unofficially announced, has been made and it will be a matter of days, I imagine, before it is implemented. https://meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/369914/57

Comment: @Mari-LouA Unless we can marshal enough votes from peeps unaware of the current poll, maybe.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Btw, in relation to your observations re point 10, that only happens if you have the question sort ordered by activity. Us old-timers know that that's what provides the most interesting viewing. But the default ordering is by time of asking and that's what most users see! :)

Comment: @Mari-LouA We are slowly and surely turning the tide!

Answer (score 4):

I'm just posting this as an answer to make an argument for unpinning. Please upvote Dan Bron's answer to practically indicate support for unpinning according to the rules Andrew Leach laid out.

I'm in favor of unpinning because the current system has no good way for anyone but the original poster to adjust the position of the pinned answer, and aside from situations where the original poster is mistaken or biased (which Dan Bron mentions, and Araucaria argues are rare), I think it's not uncommon for the original poster of a question to just not be active on the site any more.

Araucaria's answer talks about situations where there is a not-so-good (or even outright incorrect) early answer and a late better answer. I agree that the voting system isn't set up to handle this well, but there is always at least some chance for the newer answer to catch up by votes over time, especially if people use tools like bounties to draw attention to it. However, if the not-so-good early answer was accepted and the OP is no longer around, there's absolutely no way for the late answer to reach the top spot under the current system of pinning accepted answers (short of the drastic step of special diamond moderator intervention). So I don't think pinning accepted answers is a good solution to the problem of early answers having an advantage relative to late answers.

Comment: This completely ignores the fact that where there is a slew of early upvotes, sometimes by non-expert readers from the HNQ, there may be literally thousands of views per day, but this will drop to tens per day, or only a fraction of that, a week later. It may take decades to catch up. It also ignores the relative risk. The highest voted answer is currently highly visible, appearing second. The pinned answer, in those rare cases where wrong, is just an annoyance. If unpinned hundreds/thousands of useful posts will effectively vanish into obscurity buried under mediocre or worse posts.

Comment: It also ignores proportionality and numbers, There are very few of those posts where annoyingly, an egregiously wrong answer has been accepted, whereas under the new system there will be a mountain of useful posts effectively buried

Answer (score 0):

### Pin the accepted answer. Point by point:

1. The accepted answer feature constitutes one of the checks and balances to the voting system.
2. Highly upvoted answers are often just early answers.
3. Highly upvoted answers which later prove to be wrong will no longer be able to be superseded by demonstrably correct well-evidenced and well-researched answers.
4. Late answers, however good, however correct, do not get highly upvoted
5. Question posters are not thickos who are unable to recognise a later well-argued and well-evidenced answer to be better than an early one.
6. The current proposal is a disincentive—especially for experts in that area—for members who wish to post late answers. They may not expect to accrue lots of upvotes, but they can at least hope to be more widely read if their answer is accepted.
7. Given that early answers, even those which are highly upvoted, are often subsequently proved wrong, the proposal will condemn later correct answers to obscurity and promote misinformation.
8. Many of the, correctly, highest voted answers to important, popular and useful questions are so precisely because the OP was able to accept the answer and promote it to a more prominent position where it was read more frequently and thus upvoted. This will no longer happen.
9. Users are unable to downvote answers which they previously thought to be useful after a better, more well-informed, well-researched answer comes along (unless it is edited).
10. Question posters are the **only** users who are routinely alerted when a new answer is posted. The thousands of users who already saw the question and voted on the smaller number of answers do not routinely get the opportunity to revote when a later answer appears.
11. Because of the point above, question posters are the only users who are in a good position to curate their question pages. No one else will do so and then revote as new answers appear, often years later. They are in an ideal position to decide which answer should be at the top of the page.
12. Many good answers are the result of detailed or diligent research. See, for example, answers by Sven Yargs, StoneyB, Tchrist,  Mari-Lou A, JEL, Janus Bahs Jacquet. However, research takes time. If these folks give a stellar answer after a few days research, one of the ways future readers can benefit from it is if the OP selects it over an older, not well-researched but highly upvoted earlier answer. The current proposal disincentivises research.
13. SE has done a lot of work to promote the role of question posters on the SE network. For example, they recently increased the rep for votes on questions so that it matches the rep for votes on answers. The current proposal is a step backwards, demoting the importance and the agency of people who ask questions.
14. Some SE sites, for instance SO, get thousands and thousands of views by active members. So, for example, the highest voted answer on SO has over 33,000 votes. On these sites a very high number of votes over a sustained period may be the best indicator of the accuracy and helpfulness of an answer. Here, however, this is not the case.
15. There are many types of question on the EL&U network. A prominent one is Single Word Requests. The current proposal would be very appropriate for a single-word-request site. However, this is not what EL&U is meant to be. The current proposal will not be supported by serious and dedicated contributors to EL&U (in terms of content), apart from **answerers of single-word-requests** and similar type questions. Serious SWR askers, who research their questions, such as Mari Lou A, and serious askers and respondents of more linguistics-based, etymology-based questions will not be in favour of this proposal. Indeed it will reduce their contributions. If you wish to see less from Sven, JL, Mari Lou, or you wish to see less future contributors like Stoney, etc then vote for this proposal. Also do this if you want to see more people misinformed.
16. The voting system of SE and EL&U is a GOOD THING. However, it is not perfect for many reasons, including those detailed above. The 'accepted answer' feature provides a balance to this system. Just like a healthy democracy, where second chambers and the separation of the legislature, the judiciary and the police provide safety in the form of checks and balances, the same is true of the accepted answer feature in its current form. Don't vote to remove this! Keep true democracy alive!